# Remove Space in URL String Query via htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, url, redirect

I have this URL: `http://www.example.com/bundles? id=5`

There is a space right behind the question mark, befor the string query.
I need to remove the space and redirect to the correct URL
`http://www.example.com/bundles?id=5`

Is there any way to do this via htaccess?
I was able to redirect with a "regular" URL, but not with string queries.

Please help!

Answer (score 1):

You can use this htaccess rule :

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/bundles/?\s\?id=([0-9]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /bundles?id=%1 [L,R]
```